# Grant INSERT without having it

Tags: mysql, mariadb, privileges

Grant INSERT without having it.

Suppose the following code snippet is executed every time a new manager is created (with different names for the database and user account each time, of course):

```
#Executed as root
CREATE DATABASE `Manager1Section`;
CREATE TABLE Manager1Data(`SomeData` INT);
CREATE USER 'Manager1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Something';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON `Manager1Section`.`Manager1Data` TO 'Manager1'@'localhost';
GRANT CREATE, DROP ON `Manager1Section`.* TO 'Manager1'@'localhost';
GRANT CREATE USER ON *.* TO 'Manager1Section'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

And the following code is executed every time a new intern is created (again, names substituted):

```
#Executed as manager
CREATE TABLE `Manager1Section`.`Intern1Data`(`Value` INT NOT NULL);
CREATE USER 'Intern1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Something';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON `Manager1Section`.`Intern1Data` TO 'Intern1'@'localhost';
```

(Mind that this is just an example to show the hierarchical structure. I am not actually modeling a company's personnel structure.)
The manager manages a single database (Manager1Section in this example) and has a table to work with. The manager can only read and write to that table <s>but not e.g. drop it</s>. (Actually nevermind, I just realized that the manager can, in fact, drop the table. Not a big deal though.).
Each intern in this database also has a table to work with, and again, can only read and write to it but not drop it. Additionally, interns can only access their own tables, but not the manager's table and not other interns' tables.
And very importantly: The manager cannot read and write to interns' tables.
The above code would achieve this, but it is not valid. The last line in the second snippet fails. The manager does not have the SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE privileges to interns' tables and therefore cannot grant those privileges to the interns. Changing the second-to-last line in the first snippet (`` GRANT CREATE, DROP ON `Manager1Section`.* TO 'Manager1'@'localhost'; ``) to `` GRANT CREATE, DROP, SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON `Manager1Section`.* TO 'Manager1'@'localhost'; `` makes that work but it also allows the manager to read and write to interns' tables, which I want to avoid.

How can I make the manager not able to read and write to interns' tables but still grant read and write privileges to interns?
Or alternatively: How can I avoid that problem altogether?

Only allowing users to grant privileges they already have is generally a good idea and my gut feeling tells me that my intended solution is not possible because the manager could circumvent the situation by creating a spoof intern account, executing `` GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON `Manager1Section`.`Intern1Data` TO 'SpoofIntern'@'localhost'; `` (mind the mismatched user names) and then access the data through that account. But I could be missing something, so I am asking for ideas.

Comment: Giving someone `WITH GRANT OPTION` is more powerful than `SUPER`, I think.

Comment: Suggest you create a fake manager, then walk through each limitation, etc, to check them.

Comment: @RickJames According to the documentation, `SUPER` is a very powerful privilege: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super
I'd say it is definitely more powerful than `WITH GRANT OPTION`.
I don't see how SUPER helps with the problem, though.

Can you please clarify what you mean with "walk through each limitation"?

Comment: But all you need to do is `GRANT` `SUPER` to yourself?

Comment: @RickJames I think there is a misunderstanding. What do you mean with "to yourself"? There are two kinds of MySQL user accounts: Managers and Interns. The manager must create a table and grant the read/write privileges to the intern, but should not be able read/write to that table.
Neither the manager, nor the intern should have SUPER privileges.

Comment: OK, I tried it.  I stand corrected -- `WITH GRANT OPTION` needs something else (presumably `SUPER`) to be usable.